# How to optimize querying to database for real-time apps - Nodejs

Tags: node.js, database, real-time

I have created a real-time app in Nodejs and I am using socket.io to broadcast data to all the connected users in a given channel. I am making an http call to API-url for example: `http://example.com/api/token=tokenumber` every 1 sec and get new json data. This data before pushed to client-side for viewing needs to do an arithmetic operations (In order to carry out arithmetic operation, app needs to connect to db like: mongo or mysql and get the data which will be used in doing calculations).

## for example- workflow

```
step 1) make http call  [received data x=80, y=90]
step 2) connect to db   [received data a=10, b=20]
step 3) do calculation  [finalval = x*a + y*b]
step 4) push data to view
```

Here, we connect to db because those **a and b variables** are dynamic and are set by Admin using some sort of control panel.

## Issue

currently, I am connecting to db every 1 sec because I am making http call every 1 second. But I am quite sure the values of a and b will be the same until any admin user logins to control panel and changes those values. **Inshort waste of resources, I believe I am making heavy use of resource by connecting to db every 1 sec and getting same unchanged values**

How do I optimize this? how do I find out whether any change in database table has occurred or not and if any change has occurred, how do I get new values and store it using some sort of in-memory caching, so that I save time and resources by not connecting to the db when values are unchanged.

One thing to note is that, when values are changed in database table, they should reflect immediately because app is in realtime.

I am aware of the solution to do a check in database table every 1 min or 5 min to find out if the value has changed or not and depending on that cache new values. but this means that if I change the value of a and b at t0, worst case it would be update view after 1 or 5 mins, once execution to db takes place, I don't want this.

## Update

So, I have my code like I explained before: I am trying to save the values pulled from db to some variable X. but on the next call it **gets set to undefined because function test is called every N seconds. but connection to db happens only once**.

**I will be making call to DB only when the app runs and I will be calling it again whenever Admin makes any changes to DB and hits submit button.**

I don't want to make any database call but use same values pulled from Db until then. I tried storing it in a variable but the very same variable is set to undefined as soon as next call takes place.

## Code

```
//requiring model products
var Product = require('./models/product');

//Here function is an async callback 
Product.find(function (err, products) {
  if (err) return console.error(err);
  console.log("callback function results: "+products);
  //I am passing data to test function once I receive the data from MongoDB
  test(products);
});

//This function is called every N seconds
function test(val) {
//Here I am trying to store mongoDB data to variable hello
var hello = val;

//This prints only once when data from mongodb is recieved then next very second its set to undefined.

console.log("stored value from db: "+hello);
http.get("api url", function(res) {
    var body = '';
    res.on('data', function(data) {
        body += data;
    });

    res.on('end', function() {
        var parsed = JSON.parse(body);
        var dataArray = [];
        //I need access to mongoDB data right here and use it in some arithmetic operation 
        var p1 = parsed.data.example1 + hello[0].price;

        //finally push data into array
        dataArray.push(p1);

        console.log(dataArray);
        //pushing to socket channel - live
        nsp.emit('live', dataArray);
    });
});
```

}

## model

```
var mongoose = require('mongoose');
mongoose.connect('mongodb://username:pswd....');
var db = mongoose.connection;

//Product Schema
var ProductSchema = mongoose.Schema({
    name:{
        type: String
    },
    price:{
        type: Number
    },
    unit:{
        type:Number
    },
    type:{
        type:String
    }
});

var Product = module.exports = mongoose.model('Product', ProductSchema);
```

Comment: 'One thing to note is that, when values are changed in database table, they should reflect immediately because app is in realtime.' i think you answer your question so what is the problem?

Comment: what is your database?

Comment: read a and b from the database when your app starts, and store them in a variable. Then only update them when the values are changed from admin side.

Comment: @farhadamjady but to know if value has changed or not I need to connect to db every second and do the check right? I dont want simply connect to db if value has not changed in the first place

Comment: @arvinkarimi its mongoDB

Comment: @MehdiElFadil Okay, I guess I need to give it a try. Thanks

Comment: simply after changing the db or values you can emit an event to client with socket and without any additional connection! @MurlidharFichadia

Comment: if you use mongoose you have "pre,post,update,delete, etc" events. please browse this link [mongoos middleware](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/middleware.html)

Comment: @MehdiElFadil I am trying to do exactly what you said. When app runs get the values from mongodb and store it in some variable but as I said before on very next call to test function the value for the variable "hello" is set to undefined because no call is made to mongoDB again. Can you look at the update section of the question? I have commented the code explaining what needs to happen where. How do I store mongodb values in variable until next request call to mongodb by Admin?

Comment: @arvinkarimi those pre, post, update and delete methods wont work here. I am in need to run mongodb query only when user or admin makes changes to DB. I can write a code that would change values of variables when user or admin changes value in DB. but how to store those value in a variable is the issue

Comment: The posted code is invalid. Missing `}` for function `test`. Please correct it so that we get able to help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Best way to achieve this is to use Nodejs Caching: https://www.npmjs.com/package/node-cache Or https://www.npmjs.com/package/node-file-cache

It simply writes whatever data you want in a file (stores as a key value pair for as long as you want). It is easy to set, retrieve or update values. You can also get multiple key-value pair.